# How to load image to view in RCP?

Tags: java, swt, rcp

I am developing an `RCP plugin project` that includes certain views.First view take 
employee details like `name` ,`address` etc.There is an option to upload employee image using browse button.Second view shows the details that have entered in the first view.All details except photo is displaying fine.

It shows a red square in the place of photo label. My code for setting photo is shown like this :

```
 Label photoLabel = new Label(parent, SWT.NONE);
 photoLabel.setBounds(420, 233, 100, 106);           

 photoLabel.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(FormDataViewClass.class,photoUploadPath));
```

where `photoUploadPath` is string variable that contains the path of uploaded photo.
How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is the path an absolute path? Does `SWTResourceManager.getImage(...)` return an image or null?

Comment: yes. SWTResourceManager.getImage(...) returns image like Image {140719108178432}

Comment: the CLabel class may help you. it can set text and image.

several years ago, i used it in my project perfectly.

Comment: SWTResourceManager.getImage returns the red square image if it cannot find the image. The image path must be relative to the FormDataViewClass for this form of getImage call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code segment helped me to resolve the above problem.

```
byte[] uploadedImg = null;
try {
    File f1 = new File(photoUploadPath);
    double fileLen = f1.length();
    uploadedImg = new byte[(int) fileLen];
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(photoUploadPath);
    int nRead = 0;
    while ((nRead = inputStream.read(uploadedImg)) != -1) {
    System.out.println("!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" + new String(uploadedImg));
    }
    inputStream.close();

} catch (Exception e2) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}

BufferedInputStream inputStreamReader = new BufferedInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(uploadedImg));
ImageData imageData = new ImageData(inputStreamReader);
Image image = new Image(Display.getCurrent(), imageData);
photoLabel.setImage(image);
```

Comment: Remember to `dispose()` the `Image` when you don't need it anymore. Otherwise you'll leak system handles.

Answer (score 0):

If it's an RCP App, I would go with a scalable solution.

Create an `ImageCache` object, which you instantiate at the beginning of the app lifecycle (preferably in the `Activator` class of the app).

This `ImageCache` can get images (and cache them, of course) from a path relative to the plugin (e.g. plugin has a folder `icons`; then, when you need an icon, you just call `Activator.getDefault().getImage("icons/random.png");` - where `getDefault()` is the `Activator` singleton instance).

Have two of these in the `ImageCache`:

```
public ImageDescriptor getImageDescriptor(final String path)
{
    ImageDescriptor imgD = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(PLUGIN_ID, path);

    if (imgD == null)
    {
        return null; // OR a "missing icon", e.g. a red flag
    }
}
```

and

```
public Image getImage(final String path)
{
    Image image = imageCacheMap.get(path);

    if (image == null)
    {
        image = getImageDescripto(path).createImage();
        imageCacheMap.put(path, image);
    }

    return image;
}
```

Since these images need to be disposed, have a method `dispose()` in the `ImageCache` which is called in the `stop()` method of the `Activator`.

There are many approaches to this. In my opinion, this is the best one for RCP apps.

Answer (score 0):

> Java SWT Load and Resize Image to View or Editor at Dynamically

[image: ![enter image description here]

---

> Button click to open FileDialog Box and selected any image to display on specific label.

**ImageLoader** class are used to load images from, and save images to, a file or stream

**ImageData** class are device-independent descriptions of images

SWT's **Image** class can be used to display images in a GUI

```
package rcp_demo.Editor;

import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.custom.CLabel;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Image;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageLoader;


public class ProductEditor extends EditorPart {

        public static final  String ID="rcp_demo.Editor.product";
        private Text text;
        private CLabel lbl_image_text;

        private static final String[] FILTER_NAMES = {
        "Images(*.jpg)","Images(*.jpeg)","Images(*.png)","All Files (*.*)"};

        // These filter extensions are used to filter which files are displayed.
        private static final String[] FILTER_EXTS = { "*.jpg", "*.jpeg", "*.png", "*.*"};

    public void createPartControl(final Composite parent) {

        parent.setLayout(null);
        //Layout with absolute positioning components. 

        text = new Text(parent, SWT.BORDER);
        text.setBounds(25, 57, 169, 19);

        Button btnOpen = new Button(parent, SWT.NONE);
        btnOpen.setText("open");
        btnOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            @Override
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getShell(), SWT.OPEN);
            dialog.setFilterNames(FILTER_NAMES);
            dialog.setFilterExtensions(FILTER_EXTS);
            String result = dialog.open();
            if(result!=null)
               {
                   text.setText(result);
                   Image image=SWTResourceManager.getImage(result);
                   ImageData imgData = image.getImageData();
                   imgData=imgData.scaledTo(200, 200);

                   ImageLoader imageLoader = new ImageLoader();
                   imageLoader.data = new ImageData[] {imgData};
                   imageLoader.save(result, SWT.IMAGE_COPY);

                   System.out.println(imgData.width+"....."+imgData.height);
                   lbl_image_text.setBounds(25,88,imgData.width+10,imgData.height+10);
                   //Image size set to Label
                   //lbl_image_text.setBounds(25,88,image.getBounds().width+10,image.getBounds().height+10);
                   lbl_image_text.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage(result));
               }
        }
    });
    btnOpen.setText("open");
    lbl_image_text = new CLabel(parent, SWT.Resize);
    }
}
```

The **CLabel** class provides some advanced features over the Label class.
This class can display its text label and image label at the same time.

```
    lbl_image_text.setText("Welcome");
    lbl_image_text.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("Image Path"));
```