# How to load and display an image on selection of a Node in TreeViewer in eclipse e4 rcp?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp, e4

I am trying to load an image from a user selected input file and show it to the user using a `Label`. This image is a property of the selected `TreeViewer` node. So when selection changes the image (if exists) should be changed as well. (Master/Detail scenario)

The forum post [How to load image to view in RCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23752432/how-to-load-image-to-view-in-rcp) suggests that I have to manually read the image as a `byte` array.

Is there framework provided way to load and display images directly? Also if such a way exists what do I have to do to replace the image with a new one when selection changes? so that there is only one image in memory at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read an image use:

```java
ImageDescriptor desc = ImageDescriptor.createFromFile(null, "file path");

Image image = desc.createImage();
```

don't forget the dispose of the image when you are done with it.