# How to add an image to a label in SWT

Tags: swt

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794190/how-to-add-text-and-image-both-in-a-swt-label"Example"), in this example the text appears on the right side I want it to be under the image.

How to do this using SWT itself?

Comment: I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the green check mark. This helps keep the focus on older posts which still don't have answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To show an image with text underneath you'd need two labels and a layout to position them under each other

```java
Composite parent = new ...
RowLayout layout = new RowLayout( SWT.VERTICAL );
layout.center = true;
parent.setLayout( layout );
Label imageLabel = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
imageLabel.setImage( ... );
Label textLabel = new Label( parent, SWT.NONE );
textLabel.setText( "text" );
```

In order to left-align the labels, omit the `layout.center = true`.
By default, the `RowLayout` has a spacing of 3 pixels that can be changed through the `spacing` field.