# Java / SWT Interface Builder / How to set image to label

Tags: java, swt

I want to set an image into my application. I have created an label within the swt interface builder and set the property "image" to my image (within the src folder). The preview displays the correct image.

[image]

The code, generated by the interface builder is:

```
    lblTest = new Label(shell, SWT.NONE);
    lblTest.setImage(SWTResourceManager.getImage("C:\\Users\\dseek\\Desktop\\PanetHomeProxySwitch\\PlanetHomeProxySwitch\\src\\PH_group_RGB.png"));
    lblTest.setBounds(10, 10, 414, 207);
    lblTest.setText("test");
```

Yet there is no image (but the label-text displayed) within the app.

[image]

What am I missing? Help is very appreciated.

**EDIT:**

If I delete the text property, there is neither an image, nor the text label.
This is the preview:

[image]

Comment: Label can only display text **or** an image, not both.

Comment: when I delete the text property, there is neither an image or text.

Comment: [`CLabel` can do both](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794190/how-to-add-text-and-image-both-in-a-swt-label).

Comment: please observe my edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You source image has the dimensions 3012x1010, but you're restricting the size of the label to 414x207, so you can only actually see the top left corner, which appears to be transparent (or gray).

Note that the `Label` doesn't automatically rescale the image to fit. This will have to be done manually.

Comment: @DavidSeek Glad this solved your problem. Please read [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) if you haven't already and please consider using a layout instead of fixed sizes.